# Grow flexbox container height without row content overflowing

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have a flexbox page element with a min-height with a container that contains rows, and the rows contain events. The row heights are evenly distributed against the height of the container as in this example:

http://codepen.io/tysonnero/pen/LWXaMG

HTML

```
<div class="page">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="event">Event 1</div>
      <div class="event">Event 2</div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="event">Event 1</div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="event">Event 1</div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="event">Event 1</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.page {
  min-height: 300px;
  display: flex;
}

.container {
  display: flex;
  flex: 1;
  flex-direction: column;
  border: solid 1px #eee;
}

.row {
  display: flex;
  flex: 1;
  flex-direction: column;
  border: solid 1px #eee;
}
```

However, if I add several additional events to the row, the events overflow into the next row as so:

http://codepen.io/tysonnero/pen/bqQyeG

HTML

```
<div class="page">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="event">Event 1</div>
      <div class="event">Event 2</div>
      <div class="event">Event 3</div>
      <div class="event">Event 4</div>
      <div class="event">Event 5</div>
      <div class="event">Event 6</div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="event">Event 1</div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="event">Event 1</div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="event">Event 1</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I can fix that by removing display:flex from the .page, but that causes the row to not evenly distribute the min-height when the row content is minimal.

Can anything recommend the best working approach to this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you just want to remove the `flex: 1` property from `.row`, use the specific properties `flex` is short for (like `flex-grow: 1`), or specify each of the values you want to use in the shorthand property.

```css
.page {
  min-height: 300px;
  display: flex;
}

.container {
  display: flex;
  flex: 1;
  flex-direction: column;
  border: solid 1px #eee;
}

.row {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  border: solid 1px #eee;
  flex-grow: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="page">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="event">Event 1</div>
      <div class="event">Event 2</div>
      <div class="event">Event 3</div>
      <div class="event">Event 4</div>
      <div class="event">Event 5</div>
      <div class="event">Event 6</div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="event">Event 1</div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="event">Event 1</div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="event">Event 1</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Gave it a try. It worked for the overflow issue, but if I remove event elements 2-6, then the rows no longer evenly distribute their height over the container.

Comment: @TysonNero you just need to specify `flex-grow: 1` explicitly then, or add all of the values you want to your shorthand `flex` property. Updated my naswer. Mind giving it another try?

Comment: Work with that change!

Answer (score 1):

Update `.row`'s `flex` property to `flex: 1 0 auto;`.

The `flex` property is shorthand for `flex-grow`, `flex-shrink` and `flex-basis`. By setting the second value to `0` we're telling those flex items not to shrink and maintain their original size.

```css
.page {
  min-height: 300px;
  display: flex;
}

.container {
  display: flex;
  flex: 1;
  flex-direction: column;
  border: solid 1px #eee;
}

.row {
  display: flex;
  flex: 1 0 auto;
  flex-direction: column;
  border: solid 1px #eee;
}
```

```html
<div class="page">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="event">Event 1</div>
      <div class="event">Event 2</div>
      <div class="event">Event 3</div>
      <div class="event">Event 4</div>
      <div class="event">Event 5</div>
      <div class="event">Event 6</div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="event">Event 1</div>
      <div class="event">Event 1</div>
      <div class="event">Event 1</div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="event">Event 1</div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="event">Event 1</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```